# equivalent of ftp put and append in scp

Tags: unix, ftp, file-transfer, scp, mainframe

I have a legacy script which I am not able to understand.

The script is to transfer 4 files (2 ebcdic format files and 2 pdf files) in unix to mainframes through ftp.

```
ebcdic format file 1 is abc.xyz
ebcdic format file 2 is pqr.xyz
pdf file 1 is abc.pdf
pdf file 2 is pqr.pdf
mainframe file name is AM2P.BJCUN.SALCHG
```

The syntax of the command in the script is as below:

```
quote site recfm=fb
put /myfiles/abc.xyz AM2P.BJCUN.SALCHG
append /myfiles/abc.pdf AM2P.BJCUN.SALCHG
append /myfiles/pqr.xyz AM2P.BJCUN.SALCHG
append /myfiles/pqr.pdf AM2P.BJCUN.SALCHG
```

I want to achieve the same thing through SCP.

Could someone please tell what is the equivalent of put and append command of ftp in scp ??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put is just the normal scp

```
scp /path/to/source user@host:/path/to/target
```

Append only works with a little hack (and not with scp directly)

```
cat source | ssh user@host "cat >> /path/to/target"
```

Comment: You will also have to read up on how to specify a data set name  using the path name syntax.

Comment: If you need to *resume* the appending (after a network disconnection for example), you may check how many *remote* bytes were already transfered (current remote file size) and then check this answer for `cat`ing after the desired number of skipped byes:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52820/skip-first-3-bytes-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

`scp` can not append (`ssh` can, but it is not always an option). You can copy remote file, append it locally and then put it back.