# How to pass command in command to pexpext in python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, stdin, pexpect

I need in python execute this command and enter password from keyboard, this is works:

```
import os
cmd = "cat /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user2@host.net \'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys\' > /dev/null 2>&1"
os.system(cmd)
```

As you can see I want append public key to remote host via ssh.
See here: [equivalent-of-ftp-put-and-append-in-scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971490/equivalent-of-ftp-put-and-append-in-scp) and here: [copy-and-append-files-to-a-remote-machine-cat-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650312/copy-and-append-files-to-a-remote-machine-cat-error)

Of course I want it do it without user input I've try pexpect and I think command is to weird for it:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn(command=cmd, timeout=10, logfile=open('debug.txt', 'a+'))
matched = child.expect(['Password:', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
if matched == 0:
    child.sendline(passwd)
```

in debug.txt:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA..........vcxv233x5v3543sfsfvsv user1@host1
/bin/cat: |: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: ssh: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: user2@host.net: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: >: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: 2>&1: No such file or directory
```

I see two solution:

1. fix command for pexpect, that it recognize whole string as one command or,
2. inject/write passwd  to stdin as fake user, but how!?!?

Comment: unrelated: there is no need to escape single quotes inside double quotes in Python: `"_'|'_"`

Comment: have you considered `ssh-copy-id` instead?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Nope, isn't available.

Comment: [`ssh-copy-id` is just a shell script](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/contrib/ssh-copy-id). If you have openssh client installed (`ssh` command) then it should be available.

Answer (score 1):

From [the `pexpect` docs](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class):

> Remember that Pexpect does NOT interpret shell meta characters such as
>   redirect, pipe, or wild cards (`>`, `|`, or `*`). This is a
>   common mistake.  If you want to run a command and pipe it through
>   another command then you must also start a shell. For example::
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls -l | grep LOG > logs.txt"')
> child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
command = "/bin/bash -c \"cat /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user2@host.net \'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\' > /dev/null 2>&1\""
child = spawn(command=command, timeout=5)
```